# How to plot the Imaginary values of a function

Tags: plotting

When i use the following code in Mathematica9 to plot the imaginary values of the function all the values are plotted on the Y axis. It is seen that the X values are taken as zero.

```
d = 1.5;
\[Nu] = 5;
der[t_] := (Sum[((-Exp[I \[Nu]^q (t)]) (Exp[I q/2]))/\[Nu]^((2 - 
      d) q), {q, -3, 3}])
data = {#, der[#]} & /@ Range[0, 10, 0.1];
ListLinePlot[Im[data], AxesLabel -> {"t", "der(t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Can anyone please give me some suggestions for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was not sure if you want to plot first value in the pair of values against the imaginary value of the second value, or the real part of the second value against the imaginary part of the second value.

For first case

```
data2 = {First@#, Im[Last@#]} & /@ data;
ListLinePlot[data2, AxesLabel -> {"t", "der(t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]